# Bash escaping (MySQL GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES is failing)

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

There is something that Bash doesn't like. What should be escaped and how?

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass vsftpd << EOF
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MYUSERNAME\_%`.* TO 'MYUSERNAME'@'%';"
EOF
```

I get the following error:

`-bash: MYUSERNAME_%: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'MYUSERNAME'@'%'' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks do *command substitution* (same as `$()`). Try using single quotes on the outer level and double quotes for your username and hostname:

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass vsftpd 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MYUSERNAME\_%`.* TO "MYUSERNAME"@"%";'
```

You can instruct here doc to not expand variables by quoting the delimiter word, but I'm not sure if this works for command substitution too:

```
mysql --user=root --password=mypass vsftpd << 'EOF'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `MYUSERNAME\_%`.* TO 'MYUSERNAME'@'%';"
EOF
```

Comment: @user1281991: I just tried the second one, which definitely works. After my edit, the first option should work too (note the quotation marks)

Comment: Yes!! Thank you. The first one is working for me, if I am doing -e'GRANT ALL (etc...)'..
THX